# Custom Windows password filter - Password communication

Tags: c#-4.0, active-directory, directoryservices

I am capturing password change event on my DC(source domain) by implementing solution provided [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms721766%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).

Now I want to send this password, perhaps sets this password on a user on target domain. Now, this target domain is not have trust relationship with source domain. I know how I can set the password but stuck at implementing transport level security. 
My question is -

What it the best and secure solution to implement transport level security like SSL? Some examples would be of great help.

I am using C#.net and following namespaces:-

```
 System.DirectoryServices, System.DirectoryServices.Protocols, and
 system.directoryservices.accountmanagement
```

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft Identity Manager, which is included in the Windows Server license, will do this natively. You might consider using an off the shelf product rather than rolling your own.

Comment: I understand but my client don't want to use it which is why I ended up in writing all custom solution. Can you please help?  I know how to set the password but I am stuck at implementing transport level security.